# Pull back of $2$-form

Tags: differential-forms

Let $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$

be given the $2$-form $\omega = x \, dy \wedge dz$ compute the pull back if $f$ is defined via

$$(\theta, \phi) \mapsto ((2+\cos \phi)\cos \theta, (2+\cos \phi)\sin \theta, \sin \phi)$$

Then I get

\begin{align}
f^*\omega&= (2+ \cos \phi)\cos \theta \,d((2+\cos \phi)\sin \theta) \, \wedge d(\sin \phi)\\
&= (2+ \cos \phi)\cos \theta (-\sin \phi \sin \theta \,d \phi+(2+\cos \phi)\cos \theta \, d \theta) \, \wedge \cos \phi d \phi\\
&=(2+\cos \phi)^2\cos^2 \theta \cos \phi \, d \theta \, \wedge d \phi
\end{align}

My question is does the $d \phi \wedge d \phi$term cancel? After distributing the wedge product. If so then /I can take it from here.

Comment: Yes, $d\phi\wedge d\phi$ is zero since the wedge product is alternating.

Comment: @kobe did I do it correctly? ^^

Comment: Yes, looks correct to me. :-)