# Compute the pull back of this 2-form then use it to compute integral

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

So consider the smooth map defined by

$$f: \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$$

via

$$(\theta, \phi) \to ((2 + \cos \phi)\cos \theta,(2 +\cos \phi)\sin \theta, \sin \phi)$$

Let $M:=F(\Bbb{R}^2)$ as the $2$ torus with the orientation that makes $f$ orientation preserving. Then compute $f^*\omega$
where $\omega$ Is the $2$-form

$$\omega = x \, dy \, \wedge \, dz$$

I computed $f^*\omega$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486352/pull-back-of-2-form) to be

$$f^*\omega=(2+\cos \phi)^2\cos^2 \theta \cos \phi \, d \theta \, \wedge d \phi$$

I need to use this to compute $\int_M \omega$ which by diffeomorphism invariance, this just equals

$$\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} f^* \omega = \int_{\Bbb{R}^2}(2+\cos \phi)^2\cos^2 \theta \cos \phi \, d \theta \, \wedge d \phi$$

(Here
$$f:\Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow M$$
is the function I'm applying diffeomorphism invariance to)
which is a double integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty (2+\cos \phi)^2\cos^2 \theta \cos \phi \, d \theta \, d \phi$$

Am I correct thus far? In computing $\int_M \omega$.

Comment: No. You need an (orientation-preserving) diffeomorphism. Is $f$ a bijection?

Comment: @TedShifrin not, it clearly is not.

Comment: @TedShifrin it is given that $f$ is orientation preserving.

Comment: There is the slight problem with the premise of the whole question, as that map defines a topological 2 sphere, and not a 2 torus.

Comment: Also how is your map $1-1$? The functions are very obviously periodic

Comment: @NinadMunshi you're right, brain far there its only surjective.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I fixed the map,  does it define a 2 torus now?

Comment: Go back to my line of questioning. Since $f$ is clearly not a bijection, *how* are you going to compute the integral of $\omega$ over $M$?

Comment: @TedShifrin can I apply stokes theorem as the $2$ torus is the boundary of some $3$manifold?

Comment: But I need to use my result from part (a).

Comment: Either way, you need to understand how to parametrize the torus or the solid torus.